# Python - How to use calculated coefficients

Tags: python

Forgive me, but I'm a complete novice when it comes to Python (and all computer languages).

With a lot of help, I have written a simple program that I am trying to build on. After going through a few steps, which I'm not sure are relevant to my question, my script creates a plot and then applies a 2nd order polynomial fit, which yields a parabolic shape. After running the script, Python prints the three coefficients from the polyfit.

Here is my question - how can I use these coefficients without having to type them manually? I need to build on my script and add three equations that will use these coefficients (call them A, B, and C).

For example, the first equation is: `Sigma11 = A / (l*S12)^2`

I would like to be able to assign the first coefficient to a variable `A` and then use it in the equation above, but without having to type it in.

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Here is the relevant code:

```
kk,ss = QS.ScanX(Kmin, Kmax, Npoint, Sigma0)
print  str(ss)
plt.plot(kk,np.sqrt(ss))

kk,ss = QS.ScanY(Kmin, Kmax, Npoint, Sigma0)
#print  str(ss)
print  str(ss)
plt.plot(kk,np.sqrt(ss))


coef = np.polyfit(kk,ss,2)

print coef
poly = np.poly1d(coef)
plt.plot(kk, poly(kk),'r')
plt.plot(np.sqrt(ss), poly(ss),'k')

plt.xlabel('K $(1/m^2)$')
plt.ylabel('Beamsize (m)')

plt.show()
```

Comment: If python can print these coefficients, it should be trivial to assign them to variables. Please show us your relevant code section so we can be more specific.

Comment: Well polyfit returns an array, so you can probably do p = numpy.polyfit(...); A = p[0], B = p[1], C = p[3]

Comment: I have attached the relevant part of the code. I'm not sure if this is enough, but please let me know if you need more.

Comment: @Ale: More Pythonic would be `A, B, C = p`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out with the help of a friend. It also seems to be the same as what was advised by a few of you. Thank you very much for the help.

I'll post my code just in case it can help anyone else in the future:

```
plt.plot(k, SigmaX2, '.', color = 'black')
plt.plot(k, SigmaY2, '.', color = 'black')
plt.xlabel('Quadrupole Field Strength $(1/m^2)$')
plt.ylabel('Beamsize $(m^2)$')
t = plt.title('Beam Size vs. Quadrupole Field Strength', \
fontsize=18, color='blue')


CoefX = np.polyfit(k, SigmaX2, 2)
CoefY = np.polyfit(k, SigmaY2, 2)
polyX = np.poly1d(CoefX)
polyY = np.poly1d(CoefY)
print "Polyfit Coefficients (x, y):"
print CoefX
print CoefY


xs = np.arange(Xmin, Xmax, 0.01)
ys1 = polyX(xs)
ys2 = polyY(xs)

plt.plot(xs, ys1, '-', color = 'blue')
plt.plot(xs, ys2, '-', color = 'red')
plt.ylim(0, np.max(ys1))
plt.ylim(0, np.max(ys2))

plt.show()



# These are the coefficients from the poly fit, which I need to use 
# later for calculations.

Ax = float(CoefX[0])
Bx = float(CoefX[1])
Cx = float(CoefX[2])

Ay = float(CoefY[0])
By = float(CoefY[1])
Cy = float(CoefY[2])
```